# Array to String conversion

Tags: php, laravel

here's my code:

```
$menu .= $this->$item['type']($item);
```

$item['type'] is a string - 'single' and it uses method single(). Yet the browser shows me this error:

```
Array to string conversion
```

I have no idea why, since single returns a string, $item['type'] also is a string. I even tried checking this:

```
var_dump($this->$item['type']([]));
```

and it still returns the same error. Do you know why?

Comment: Have you tried (string)($this->$item['type']($item));

Comment: did you try to see var_dump($this->$item['type']); it returns what ?

Comment: seifeddine Besbes - it's the same error

Comment: there is one explanation that $item['type'] is an array, perhaps an array contains your string try to see what $item['type'] returns to know for sure

Comment: that's the problem, I've tried multiple times and it always returns  string(6) "single"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the string that was found in the array element in curly brackets before using it as a method name to your object:

```
$menu .= $this->{$item['type']}($item);
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: I'm just curious - did it suppose to work in ealier versions of PHP? I have project that was running php 5.6 and I was working on 7.0 when it stopped working.

Comment: Well, honestly, I don't know. But looking at it again, I can understand, why the brackets are needed here. Without them PHP (any version!) would have to "think" that you want to access the function under the `$type`-th element of the object property `$this->$time` (assuming `$time` to be a string!). The curly brackets force PHP to evaluate the term`$time[$type]` first.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this will work try it :

```
$method = $item['type'];
var_dump($this->$method($item));
```

Comment: it does and I have no idea why. Care to explain?

Comment: yes sure, as we know php support variable functions but only simple variable. it does not support array as variable function.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php